# ASP.NET Access to path '\\xxxx' is denied

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, unc, file-security

I know this has come up in other questions, but none seem as simple:

I have a UNC share on another machine, with security set to `Full Control` for `Everyone`.  If I log into my web server, I can access this share.

However when I try to access it using `Directory.GetFiles(path)` in the ASP.NET code, it returns an `Access to the path \\xxxx is denied.` error.

Also oddly, when I run the same website from my local visual studio web server, but pointing at the same path, the directory can be accessed fine.

What am i missing here?!

Comment: maybe there is an issue with the IIS user, or a security configuration with the IIS

Comment: Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Maybe a security configuration within the IIS or a firewall issue

Comment: Not firewall, as i can access the path on same server

Comment: Maybe not the network firewall but the internal application firewall from windows server, their tend to be more secured and protected. And you are accesing the share with the windows user but sadly the code will try to access with the "IIS User" and the IIS application that might be blocked by the firewall

Comment: "Everyone" includes the accounts you mention

Comment: What is the identity used by the appdomain of your website? Are these servers domain joined? Are you using a domain account?

Comment: Yes to Domain joined, and the IIS Application pool uses a domain account that has full control over the directory.  How do I find which appdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Add IUSR, IIS_IUSRS as suggested by Carlos487 and Network Service as well with full control on the directory that you are trying to access with your application. Hope this helps.

Comment: "Everyone" includes the accounts you've listed.  Anyhow, tried explicitly adding and didn't help...

Comment: Check the filesystem permissions on the folder that's being shared out. Granting `Full Control` to `Everyone` on the **share** is not sufficient by itself - the filesystem ACLs on the folder being shared must also allow access to the web server user.